# Is it possible under Windows Server 2012 to run Terminal Services but have it run a VM?

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows-terminal-services, hyper-v-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 box that I'd like to be able to host up to 5 TS instances on it. However, it would be ideal if those instances could actually fire up a Hyper-V VM running Windows 7. So from the end users perspective, they would RDP into a server and get a Windows 7 instance.

I know I could configure RDP on my Windows 7 VM and, if the VM is left running, a user could connect to it. However, that only works for 1 client (and only if the VM is running). I need to have up to 5 people connection (and having 5 different addresses wouldn't work very well for them). I am OK with having 5 different VMs set-up to support this.

I've done some searching but haven't stumbled across the right combination of keywords to find anything (heck, it may not even be possible).

Is this even possible? And if so, could you point me to any documentation about how to go about configuring this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you are looking for is VDI - Virtual Desktop Infrastructure.  It's a pretty wide topic - there are entire books written about it.  But knowing that term should get you started on finding the appropriate guides.

Comment: Or possibly application virtualization, but yeah, either way, big topic.